# Bootbox, 2 alerts, one above another

Tags: jquery, bootbox

I have two bootbox modal windows - one is a prompt while the other is an alert. If user enters the wrong data and try to submit, another bootbox alert appears appears. After the user clicks on ok, the prompt is called once again. The problem is the second alert is covered by the prompt that is called the second time. Is it possible to prevent the prompt (which is called a second time) to cover the alert? There doesn't seem to be anything in http://bootboxjs.com/v3.x/documentation.html.

my code:

```
bootbox.prompt("what's your name?", "No", "yes", function(result) {                
      if (result != null) {                                             
        if(result.trim() == ""){
            bootbox.alert("The name cannot be empty.");   

        }else{
                bootbox.alert("Supplier name can only be 15 characters long.");
                supplierPrompt(location);
            }
      }
    }, "Default name eg S1");
```

Edit:
After the alert, the prompt is called once again. The second time the prompt is called, it blocks the alert.

Comment: what actually you want? Alert should be on top of Prompt?

Comment: Just edited by question after realizing what was the issue after looking at the lab demo you gave,

Answer (score 0):

Yes alert can be on top of Prompt its just designed to be like that.
See Simple Demo on [**Labs**](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/I~W57vq!steG95NHw2!4NZMVB1SgC~VF)

and if in your case Promt is comming on top of alert then it can be **your CSS issue** Let us know you code or please create a **[Lab Demo](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab)**

Answer (score 0):

inside the else:

```
    bootbox.dialog("The supplier name cannot be empty.", {
        "label" : "ok",
        "class" : "btn-primary",   // or btn-primary, or btn-danger, or nothing at all
        "callback": function() {
            supplierPrompt(location);
        } 
    }, {
        "animate": true
    });
```

This prevents the second calling of the prompt (supplierPrompt(..)) from being called until the user clicks on ok.